# Trying to use Faster-rcnn models

Tags: android, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a question. I am trying to implement real-time object detection on mobile and I am facing a few problems. I retrained mobilenet along with a few faster RCNN models using my own data. The problem I am facing is that mobilenet is extremely inaccurate in my case yet it is the only one that I can use on mobile since the more accurate faster rcnn are simply too heavy for my Samsung A7. Is there a way to optimize the RCNN to work on the mobile? Or do I have to keep working on mobilenet and trying to make it more accurate?

I really prefer to use RCNN since it is much more accurate and i am short on time to find more data to retrain mobilenet